# Custom SecurityTokenValidator works but still unauthorized

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, jwt

I'm having some troubles in dotnet core with JWT validation.

I have created a custom validator, instead of validating the token, it will be forwarded to another API and return the token. This works perfectly, however, I keep getting the response: unauthorized.

This is my validator, quite simple, it validates the token, if it gets a response, it should be okay.

```
public class JwtValidator : ISecurityTokenValidator
{
    AuthenticationClient authClient;

    public JwtValidator(AuthenticationClient authClient)
    {
        this.authClient = authClient;
    }

    public bool CanValidateToken => true;

    public int MaximumTokenSizeInBytes { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public bool CanReadToken(string securityToken)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken)
    {
        validatedToken = null;

        //your logic here
        var response = authClient.Validate(securityToken);
        //assuming response will contain info about the user

        if (response == null)
            throw new SecurityTokenException("invalid");

        validatedToken = response.Result;

        return new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(response.Result.Claims));
}
```

No exception is being thrown, the token is valid, claims are being returned.

In Startup.cs I have the following code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
            options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new JwtValidator(authClient));
        });
```

When I add logging to the JwtValidator I do get logs, so the function appears to be called correctly. But the API keeps returning "Unauthorized".

Comment: Did you get that working in the end? I'm at a spot where I'm not sure what to return as *validatedToken* so I'm pushing out *new JwtSecurityToken()* and a bunch of other variations. Then I get *401 bagger off you untrustworthy bum* and I strongly suspect that it's got to do with that. Or possibly with the *ClaimsPrincipal* instance. Otherwise, everything else seems to work just fine...

Answer (score 1):

The way I implemented a custom JWT handler in .net core 5 is by inheriting from JwtSecurityTokenHandler instead of  ISecurityTokenValidator (this is the base interface of SecurityTokenValidator). Then in order to validate the token I called

```
var claimsPrincipal = base.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
```

which directly returns the ClaimsPrinciple.
In your code I suspect the AuthenticationClient may be the issue.
Below is my validation code.

```
public class JwtValidator : JwtSecurityTokenHandler
{
    // Define constructor and other custom attributes   
   public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string securityToken, 
   TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, 
   out SecurityToken validatedToken)
    {
         var claimsPrincipal = base.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
         return claimsPrincipal;
    }
}
```